# Firefox 51 fails to load img data via ftp

Tags: html, firefox, ftp, apache2

I have just stumbled across some behavior that looks weird to me.

There is a small static test page on my webserver that has the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="ftp://my-ftp-server/t.jpg">
  <img src="ftp://my-ftp-server/t.jpg"/></a>
<br>image
</body>
</html>
```

When I load the page in Firefox 51, the image on the page is shown as broken. In the standard Firefox developer console I do not see any requests (well, it is an FTP request, so not surprising it is not shown in HTTP requests list).

When I click on the image box, the image loads correctly.

What I checked so far:

- Both links are identical.
- The page opens in Google Chrome 56 correctly.
- When I change the image data link from ftp to http (the ftp server is accessible via http) the page loads correctly in Firefox.
- This does not seem to be a caching issue (clearing the cache does not resolve it)
- There is no AdBlock or similar add-ons installed.
- Developer console shows "*Could not load the*" tooltip when mouse hovers over the image link.
  [image]

What could be the reason for Firefox 51 not displaying the image with data accessible via FTP?

**Details:** This is Mozilla Firefox 51.0.1 built for OpenSUSE Leap 42.1. So far I could not reproduce neither on Google Chrome, nor on Firefox 50.1.0.

Comment: Certainly, neither Firebug not builtin developer tools appear to support FTP in their network panes, but nevertheless the picture is loading fine in my browser (Firefox/51.0.1 Win64). I guess that means that it *should* work.

Comment: I just posted the same exact problem yesterday, not realizing it had been asked before.  Did anyone figure this out?   Works in any browser except firefox.  I have firefox 53.   The only way I could get around this was to use an iframe instead of an img tag.   I'd rather use img though.   Let me know if you ever got this to work.